# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 C# Save Device Setting

Tags: c#, save, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10, user-config

I would like to know how to save my user config for my selected USB devices. Whenever i restart the device it will load as i selected previously.
is it advisable to save locally or in the usb storage?

Does this app note [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) applicable as types of app data mentioned works with USB adapter?

[image: selected devices]

Updated:

When I selected the USB adapter from the listbox, I set the respective selected device accordingly.

```
        private void audioCaptureList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            recordPlayer.AudioDevice = captureDeviceList[audioCaptureList.SelectedIndex];
        }

        private void audioRenderList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            mediaPlayer.AudioDevice = renderDeviceList[audioRenderList.SelectedIndex];

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setting can be saved as [Local app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#local-app-data). These data will not change even you restart the device. But **note:** [the lifetime of the app data is tied to the lifetime of the app. If the app is removed, all of the app data will be lost as a consequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).

You can store and retrieve local app data like this:

```
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    private void StoreButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selection = ConnectDevices.SelectedItems;
        var entry = (DeviceListEntry)selection[0];
        var device = entry.DeviceInformation;

        localSettings.Values["SelectedUsbDeviceId"] =  device.Id;
        localSettings.Values["SelectedUsbDeviceName"] = device.Name;
    }

    private void RetrieveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Object deviceId = localSettings.Values["SelectedUsbDeviceId"];
        Object deviceName = localSettings.Values["SelectedUsbDeviceName"];
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rita, may i know what is devicelistentry referring to? as i can understand, "ConnectDevices" is referring to the ListBox in my case "audioRenderList". Please correct me if i am wrong.  I have also updated my selectionchanged code. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Rita, after i declared 'Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = 
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;' it triggered  exception handler. Is there anything else I need to take care of?

Comment: @mylim You can find devicelistentry [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess/cs/DeviceListEntry.cs). What's the exception?